# Fancybox cache issue (registered and unregistered user)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, caching, fancybox

We are using a fancybox on our site. Registered users can see top panel on the fancybox, unregistered can't see it.

At first boot of images there are request to the server, create a template that displays a picture. But after the first click there is no request to the server - therefore if we click by registered user and after make log out and click again we see that top panel.

There is c# checking if user registered or not:

```
@if (isOwner && Model.MultimediaTypeId == KZStream.Web.Site.Models.Multimedia.MultimediaTypes.Image )
 {
    //show top panel
 }
 else{
    //hide top panel
 }
```

There is fancybox calling:

```
   this.cont.find("a.imglnk").fancybox({
            'opacity': true,
            'overlayShow': true,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            type: 'ajax',
            ajax: { global: false, cache: false },
            titleShow: false,
            scrolling: 'no',
        });
```

There is template by which we get picture (C#):

```
<div style="position: relative" id="mmgf_@(prefix)" class="mmgf">
   @if (isOwner && Model.MultimediaTypeId == KZStream.Web.Site.Models.Multimedia.MultimediaTypes.Image )
    { 
       <div class="fancy-box-top-panel">

        <div class="choose-album-cover">
            <div style='min-height: 22px; display: inline-block;'>
                <div class='checkbox-test cb_gray'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='choose-album-cover' name='choose-album-cover' value='on' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="album-cover">
                @RenderMultimediaGalleryStrings.ChooseAlbumCover</div>
        </div>

        <div class="dn manage-album-cont">
            <div class="move-dp-btn">
                <a href="#" class="move-button">@RenderMultimediaGalleryStrings.Move</a>
                <div class="dn move-drop-down-list">
                    @if (albums != null && albums.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var alb in albums)
                        {                             
                        <a href="#" class="move-dp-links" data-album-id="@alb.Id">@alb.Name</a>
                        }
                    }
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
        </div>
    </div> }
    <div style="width: 630px; height: 440px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; position: relative;">
        @if (Model.MultimediaTypeId == KZStream.Web.Site.Models.Multimedia.MultimediaTypes.Image)
        {
            <img src="@(Html.KZStreamImagePath(Model.Id, 630, 440))" style="text-align: center;position: absolute;margin: auto;top: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;" />
        }
        else
        {
            <iframe width="632" height="414" src="@(Html.Action("GetVideo", new { id = Model.Id }))" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
        }
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14px; color: #000000; max-width: 630px;">
        @Model.Description
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally i need that at every image showing there are carried out an inspection :) Thanks :)

Comment: I am at a loss to understand what you are doing/saying.  Could you add a bit more relevant code or detail to clarify?

Comment: question is updated..

Comment: Please clarify what `carried out an inspection` means.

Comment: i mean checks the if() condition..(is it registered use or not)..

Comment: paqogomez, ANY IDEA BRO?))